# Finding the right SPI pins on the Rapsberry for Digital Pot MCP42010

Tags: spi

Here is the data sheet for the MCP42010:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/11195c.pdf

Here are my best guesses:

- Pin 1 CS goes to Pin 11 / SPI1 CS0 (GPIO17)
- Pin 2 SCK goes to Pin 23 / SCLK (GPIO11)
- Pin 3 SI goes to Pin 19 / SPI0 MOSI (GPIO10)
- Pin 4 VSS goes to Ground
- Pin 5, 6, 7 are pot connections
- Pin 8, 9, 10 are pot connections
- Pin 11 and 12, I have no idea.
- Pin 13 goes to Pin 21 / SPI0 MISO (GPIO9)
- Pin 14 to positive

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.  I've searched online for pinouts for ANY digital pot without any luck.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to use CE0_0 (or even CE1_0) when using SPI0 for every other connection, i.e. SCLK_0, MISO_0 and MOSI_0, rather than randomly choosing CE1_1 for some unknown reason

Comment: Sorry, you lost me.  What is CE0_0?  Is that related to Raspberry Pi?

Comment: SPI1 CS0 ... that's SPI ONE, Chip select zero ... though, I've seen it labelled as CE1_1 - i.e. chip select 1 spi 1 ... there's lot's of conflicting info out there - but it's still a chip select for SPI ONE ... yet you use SPI ZERO for MOSI, MISO and CLOCK - that was my point ... use SPI ZERO chip select not SPI ONE

Answer (score 2):

Pi pin 11 (GPIO 17) is chip select 1.  If you want to use chip select 0 you need to use Pi pin 12 (GPIO 18).

Device pin 11 (reset input) and device pin 12 (shutdown input) should be connected to 3V3 or 5V depending on whether you are powering the device from 3V3 or 5V (perhaps just strap to device pin 14).

There is no point in connecting device pin 13 to the Pi.  It is just a pass through of the commands you send.

The rest of the connections look fine.